# GCP Project migration without support contract

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am in the process of moving some projects from a GCP account attached to a GSuite Org (@example.com) to a personal Google Account (@gmail.com).

I have changed the billing account to a new one under the @gmail account - however I believe this is not enough to migrate them fully.

GSuite account view shows under org id:

[image: gsuite account]

GMail account view shows under no org:

[image: gmail account view]

I was reading the documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#open-support-case

I do not have a support contract so went to this page:

https://console.cloud.google.com/support/community

Which prompted me to use the #google-cloud-platform tag here.

I need to be able to eventually shutdown the old GSuite org while keeping my projects running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot move a project in an organization to be a separate project without Google's help. You will need a Google Cloud Premium support package and you will need to open a support ticket.

Comment: So am I right in saying that this operation is not possible unless I have a google premium support package?

Comment: @CharlieEgan - Correct.